# Values Turning Into 0s When Uploading CSV As Table In BigQuery

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I am relatively new to SQL and am having an issue when uploading csv files as tables in my dataset. I obtained these csv files from an open-source dataset on Kaggle (FitBit Fitness Tracker Data from https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/arashnic/fitbit).

I was able to transfer 6 other csv files from this very dataset without this issues, but suddenly these other csv files are replacing entire column values with 0s, no matter what data type I input (I even tried string). I am worried that somehow it is rounding the value, even as a string, and even though I did not input any rounding options.

I tried multiple different data types, including string, floats, numeric, and bignumeric. I tried adding precision and accuracy values, and I have been manually inputting the schema instead of auto detect, but all to no avail. I tried messing with the csv in excel and changed the columns to number or decimal to ensure it reads correctly, but even so it is turned to 0s when uploaded.

I would greatly appreciate any help on this.